# Converting byte array to publickey ECDSA

Tags: java, key, signature, public-key, ecdsa

I need to use ECDSA algorithm to sign a message and send to receiver in java. Then, receiver should verify sender's signature.

So, for this, receiver has sender's public key but in byte array format after converting `java.security.PublicKey` to byte array by the command bellow:

```
byte[] byteArrayPublicKey = publickey.getEncoded();
```

The format of public key in ECDSA algorithm (before converting it to byte array) is as follow:

Public Key:

```
X: 8a83c389e7bb817c17bf2db4ed71055f18342b630221b2a3a1ca752502dc2e21

Y: 3eaf48c9ab1700fe0966a0cde196b85af66bb8f0bacef711c9dca2368f9d8470
```

But, the problem is to convert this byte array to usable format to verify the signature that is `java.security.PublicKey` by receiver.

In general, is there any solution to verify the signature without converting it to byte array? In the other word, the problem is to verify the signature by sender's public key, using any method.

Comment: If you have the result of `PublicKey.getEncoded()` that is **not** just the public point X and Y; it contains an AlgId including parameters as well. Java calls that "X509" encoding, and you can feed it directly to `KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePublic()`. If you actually have only separate point coordinates **and the curve**, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646792/how-does-one-convert-a-public-ec-code-point-and-curve-name-into-a-publickey and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445997/loading-raw-64-byte-long-ecdsa-public-key-in-java .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, the problem is to convert this byte array to usable format to verify the signature that is java.security.PublicKey by receiver.

You can solve the problem like this way:

```
public static ECPublicKey genEcPubKey() throws Exception {
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
    java.security.PublicKey ecPublicKey = (ECPublicKey) factory
            .generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(Helper
                    .toByte(ecRemotePubKey))); // Helper.toByte(ecRemotePubKey)) is java.security.PublicKey#getEncoded()
    return (ECPublicKey) ecPublicKey;
}
```

Note that, you need [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) provider to do that.

But question remains, how you generate the private key?

```
public KeyPair ecKeyPairGenerator(String curveName) throws Exception {
    KeyPair keyPair;
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
            "ECDSA", "BC");
    ECGenParameterSpec ecGenParameterSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec(
            curveName);
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(ecGenParameterSpec, new SecureRandom());
    keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    java.security.PublicKey ecPublicKey = (ECPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
    System.out.println("JAVA EC PublicKey: "
            + Helper.toHex(ecPublicKey.getEncoded()));

    // write private key into a file. Just for testing purpose
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
            "ECPrivateKey.key");
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
            fileOutputStream);
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(keyPair.getPrivate());
    objectOutputStream.close();
    return keyPair;
}
```

I have the full running code for EC sign/verify in [github](https://github.com/rakeb/ECPSingVerify). You can take a look for better understanding.

Comment: Rakeb void, thank you so much for your useful and great answer. just another thing should be added that I explained it in another question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956867/signature-verification-is-always-false-java?noredirect=1#comment49946507_30956867
the matter is respecting ASN.1 in signature and verification.

Comment: If this is the answer you are looking for then try to accept it. Ty.

Comment: I try to vote for it to accept this answer, but in fact, minimum 15 reputation is needed for this. My reputation is 7. I try to do this as soon as I'm able to vote.

Comment: Is there way to use without "BC"?  I wonder whether oracle jre has ECDSA algorithm for KeyFactory?

Comment: how can I do this in C/C++?

Comment: @HaiBi: Oracle Java 7 and up has the SunEC provider which has (one) `KeyFactory` named `EC` whose resulting keys are usable for both `ECDSA` and `ECDH` algorithms. And the same for `KeyPairGenerator`.