# How to make a Bouncy Castle ECPublicKey

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I know the curve name (`secp256k1`) and the `X` and `Y` coordinates of the EC public key.

How do I make a `org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPublicKey` out of them?

I've read https://stackoverflow.com/a/29355749/5453873 but the code there uses `java.security...` instead of `org.bouncycastle...` and ECPublicKey is an interface in `org.bouncycastle...` not an instantiable class.

Comment: Do you really need to use the org.bouncycastle.* classes? I would expect you will be better off trying to use the JCE API with BC just as a provider. Alternatively, if you don't mind the direct dependency on BC then things might be simpler if you just use the lightweight (i.e. non-JCE) API directly.

Comment: @PeterDettman there's a non-JCE API for bouncycastle?  I'm using BC's ECIES - does this mean I should stick to the JCE API?

Comment: Please don't forget to indicate the language / runtime (Java) as well as additional tags such as cryptography. Not that many people follow [tag:bouncycastle].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Generating ECPublicKey using Bouncy Castle

This generates the EC public key as used in the JCE/JCA. The Bouncy Castle provider can directly use these software keys. Otherwise Bouncy is just used to generate the parameters required to generate the public key.

```
package nl.owlstead.stackoverflow;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.US_ASCII;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.ECPoint;
import java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.ECNamedCurveTable;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECNamedCurveParameterSpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECNamedCurveSpec;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class ECPublicKeyFactory {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String name = "secp256r1";

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // === NOT PART OF THE CODE, JUST GETTING TEST VECTOR ===
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "BC");
        ECGenParameterSpec ecGenParameterSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec(name);
        kpg.initialize(ecGenParameterSpec);
        ECPublicKey key = (ECPublicKey) kpg.generateKeyPair().getPublic();
        byte[] x = key.getW().getAffineX().toByteArray();
        byte[] y = key.getW().getAffineY().toByteArray();

        // === here the magic happens ===
        KeyFactory eckf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
        ECPoint point = new ECPoint(new BigInteger(1, x), new BigInteger(1, y));
        ECNamedCurveParameterSpec parameterSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec(name);
        ECParameterSpec spec = new ECNamedCurveSpec(name, parameterSpec.getCurve(), parameterSpec.getG(), parameterSpec.getN(), parameterSpec.getH(), parameterSpec.getSeed());
        ECPublicKey ecPublicKey = (ECPublicKey) eckf.generatePublic(new ECPublicKeySpec(point, spec));
        System.out.println(ecPublicKey.getClass().getName());

        // === test 123 ===
        Cipher ecies = Cipher.getInstance("ECIESwithAES", "BC");
        ecies.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ecPublicKey);
        byte[] ct = ecies.doFinal("owlstead".getBytes(US_ASCII));
        System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(ct));
    }
}
```

### Generating Bouncy Castle ECPublicKeyParameters

Initially I thought that a Bouncy Castle specific key was required, so the following  code generates the EC public key as used in the Bouncy Castle lightweight API.

```
package nl.owlstead.stackoverflow;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.ECNamedCurveTable;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9ECParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECNamedDomainParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECPublicKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECCurve;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class BC_EC_KeyCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String name = "secp256r1";

        // === NOT PART OF THE CODE, JUST GETTING TEST VECTOR ===
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "BC");
        kpg.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec(name));
        ECPublicKey key = (ECPublicKey) kpg.generateKeyPair().getPublic();
        byte[] x = key.getW().getAffineX().toByteArray();
        byte[] y = key.getW().getAffineY().toByteArray();

        // assumes that x and y are (unsigned) big endian encoded
        BigInteger xbi = new BigInteger(1, x);
        BigInteger ybi = new BigInteger(1, y);
        X9ECParameters x9 = ECNamedCurveTable.getByName(name);
        ASN1ObjectIdentifier oid = ECNamedCurveTable.getOID(name);
        ECCurve curve = x9.getCurve();
        ECPoint point = curve.createPoint(xbi, ybi);
        ECNamedDomainParameters dParams = new ECNamedDomainParameters(oid,
                x9.getCurve(), x9.getG(), x9.getN(), x9.getH(), x9.getSeed());
        ECPublicKeyParameters pubKey = new ECPublicKeyParameters(point, dParams);
        System.out.println(pubKey);

        // some additional encoding tricks
        byte[] compressed = point.getEncoded(true);
        System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(compressed));
        byte[] uncompressed = point.getEncoded(false);
        System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(uncompressed));
    }
}
```

This was mostly tricky because I didn't want to include any JCE specific code, and `X9ECParameters` is not a subclass of `ECDomainParameters`. So I used a conversion to `ECNamedDomainParameters` copied from elsewhere in the code base of Bouncy Castle.

Comment: Thanks for your work.  With bcpkix-jdk15on-152.jar and bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar `org.bouncycastle.jce.ECNameCurveTable` does not have the methods `getByName` nor `getOID`, so the code won't compile.

Comment: Also an `org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECPublicKeyParameters` isn't an `org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPublicKey`, which is what I think I need to call `init` on the "ECIESwithAES" `javax.crypto.Cipher`.

Comment: Thanks for your work - I don't yet have enough rep to upvote your answer, but I will when I do.  I've found a simpler method that achieves what I need.

Answer (score 4):

In the code which follows, `encoded` contains `0x04` followed by 32 bytes of X, then 32 bytes of Y.

Alternatively, it can contain `0x02` or `0x03` (dependent on the sign of Y) followed by 32 bytes of X.

```
public static ECPublicKey decodeKey(byte[] encoded) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException{
    ECNamedCurveParameterSpec params = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
    ECCurve curve = params.getCurve();
    java.security.spec.EllipticCurve ellipticCurve = EC5Util.convertCurve(curve, params.getSeed());
    java.security.spec.ECPoint point = ECPointUtil.decodePoint(ellipticCurve, encoded);
    java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec params2 =EC5Util.convertSpec(ellipticCurve, params);
    java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec keySpec = new java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec(point,params2);
    return (ECPublicKey) fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
}
```

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I've accepted your answer, as it's more generally useful.

Answer (score 4):

A shorter variation on Thomas' answer, which does not use a `KeyFactory` would be:

```java
public static ECPublicKey decodeKey(byte[] encoded) {
  ECNamedCurveParameterSpec params = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");
  ECPublicKeySpec keySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(params.getCurve().decodePoint(encoded), params);
  return new BCECPublicKey("ECDSA", keySpec, BouncyCastleProvider.CONFIGURATION);
}
```

I assume that `encoded` was obtained by `BCECPublicKey.getQ().getEncoded(bool)`, i.e. it is a byte `0x2-0x4` followed by one or two affine coordinates of the public point on `secp256k1`.

Answer (score 1):

ECUtil Already provided

```
ECPublicKeyParameters bcecPublicKey =(ECPublicKeyParameters) ECUtil.generatePublicKeyParameter(kp.getPublic());
ECPrivateKeyParameters bcecPrivateKey = (ECPrivateKeyParameters) ECUtil.generatePrivateKeyParameter(kp.getPrivate());
```