# Can't cast ECPublicKeyImpl to BCECPublicKey

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, encryption-asymmetric, ecdsa

I would like to get a compressed EC public key representation, and I did this by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51349758/9545837) answer.
But when I try to cast a `java.security.PublicKey` to a `org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPublicKey` I get an exception:

```
jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECPublicKeyImpl cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPublicKey
```

Imports:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;
```

Code:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
ECGenParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
keyGen.initialize(ecSpec, random);
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

ECPoint ecPoint = ((BCECPublicKey) pair.getPublic()).getQ(); - Exception

System.out.println(new String(ecPoint.getEncoded(true)));
```

Comment: You can create an instance with `BCECPublicKey bcecPublicKey = new BCECPublicKey((ECPublicKey)pair.getPublic(), BouncyCastleProvider.CONFIGURATION)` and get the public key in compressed format with `bcecPublicKey.getQ().getEncoded(true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(String)` gets you the first security provider that implements the given algorithm. Without further configuration it is ["SunEC"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunEC).

Since you clearly want to rely on **BouncyCastle** to generate your key, use the 2 parameter factory method:

```java
final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
```

However, if you were to receive the `KeyPair` object as parameter, you can not assume it comes from BouncyCastle and you should convert it manually to a `BCECPublicKey` as in Topaco's comment:

```java
final BCECPublicKey pubKey = pair.getPublic() instanceof BCECPublicKey
  ? (BCECPublicKey) pair.getPublic()
  : new BCECPublicKey((ECPublicKey) pair.getPublic(), BouncyCastleProvider.CONFIGURATION);
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33347595/11748454): your data just contains a point coordinates, you need the curve to have a public key.